# Vim: typing lparen "(" shifts entire line to the right

Tags: vim

I hope this is not off-topic, but I don't know where else to ask. When typing in insert mode, only in .tex files, typing a lparen shifts the entire line to the right by my tabstop. Typing an rparen does nothing; the shift is preserved. I notice that this happens in both regular vi, vim, and nvim. Is there a way to disable this feature?

Comment: I can reproduce it within the theorem environment, e.g.: \begin{theorem} text... $O(  \end{theorem}. After the lparen is typed the entire line shifts to the right by one tab. It does not seem to happen when writing text outside of the theorem environment. As you suggested, it does not happen when running `vim -u NONE`, so it must be some package/option I have enabled. I will try to track it down and post back if I figure it out.

Comment: I should note that it is not just lparen, but any unclosed object like { or [ that triggers this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by the `indentkeys` option. If it contains `(`, vim will automatically indent current line whenever a `(` is inserted. If it contains `0(`, then it will indent only when `(` is inserted *at the beginning* of the line. To see the content of the option, type in `:set indentkeys?`

To answer your question, you may try to put the following in `ftplugin/tex.vim` in the vim directory (`vimfiles` on windows, `~/.vim` on linux)

```
setlocal indentkeys-=(
setlocal indentkeys-=0(
...
```

Configurations in `ftplugin/tex.vim` are only applied when the `filetype` of the buffer is set to `tex`. And using `setlocal` allows you to modify the option only for the *current tex buffer*, so it won't override the options for other buffers which are not LaTeX files.

For more explanations, see

- [`:h 'indentkeys`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27indentkeys%27)
- [`:h indentkeys-format`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#indentkeys-format)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In normal mode, when in your `tex` file, write:

```
:set noautoindent
```

Then test that your issue is resolved.

If you want to disable it for all `tex` files, always, you can create a subfolder structure in your `.vim` (on Unix-like systems; for Windows it's `vimfiles` I think) directory: `.vim/ftplugin/tex/`. Then add one text file with just `set noautoindent` in the `tex` directory. Name the file something like `settings.vim`.

Comment: I would like to add, informally, that indentation is awesome and should be used.

Comment: I initially wrote: "You can add this to your `vimrc` (without the colon) if you want to disable indentation globally in vim." But this is wrong. You should use `filetype indent off` (or erase `filetype indent on`) for that. But don't.